# Is it possible to split React Admin application to multiple roots?

Tags: next.js, react-admin

Is it possible to somehow *split* the React Admin application across multiple Next.js pages (which is essentially different files)? I'd like to see if that could help us cut down on loading time of the page/bundle, maybe we could leverage some of the features provided by Next.js too.

My guess would be no, due to React Admin originating from a single root component, but I'd like to know for sure. And while I could have multiple roots in various pages, every page is essentially the same application, just duplicated